# Android Studio sample project Build Errors

Tags: android

I am using the sample project that is loaded with `Android Studio`.

I have bought a copy of `Android Studio Essentials` and have worked through the sample project.

When it is time to run the project, I get a `BUILD FAILED` warning.

The error is -

```
 Could not find any verfsion that matched com.android.support-v4:20.+. 
 Required by: MyApplication2:app:unspecified.
```

Looking forward to resolving this.

Thanks

Peter

Comment: Can you check in the SDK Manager if `com.android.support-v4:20` is downloaded?

Comment: post your build.gradle please

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am new to this. Where do I check if the com.android.support is loaded.

Comment: How do I post the build gradle

Answer (score 0):

assume you have an experience in android development using Eclipse before. You can read a link below to build in Studio.

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html

Comment: Sorry I have no android development experience, however I have had some java and lots of php development practice.